# Mantis: Show a List of Cases that are Assigned to Me

Tags: mantis

Is there anyway to get a list of cases that are assigned to me, in [Mantis](http://www.mantisbt.org/)?

Answer (score 3):

Try using the Extended Filter functioanllity and set it to "assigned to" --> your login.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options for seeing the testcases assigned to you

**Option 1**

- Log in
- Click on "Main" link from the top navigation

Find for "Open and assigned to me" label. This label has the count of tickets assigned to you.
The count/number is linked.

**Option 2**

- Log in
- Click on "View issues" link from the top navigation
- Use filter.

Enter your user name in "Assigned to" filter and select "Status" of the tickets to be looked for.